# store value in session and retrive on tpl file xcart

Tags: php, session, smarty, x-cart

i am facing problem in x-cart,
i am trying to create session and store value in x-cart 
for that, i used

```
x_session_register('subscription');
```

and the simple variable in it

```
$rs=1;
if($rs==1)
{
  $subscription=1;
}
else
{
  $subscription=0;
}
```

after that used some code in tpl file like,

```
{$smarty.session.subscription}
```

but nothing happen
i also tried

```
{php}{/php}
$_SESSION[''];
```

but cant help me, i cant understand whats going wrong with that
there is different file and template also file path is different
try to create session in login.php and want this in head.tpl file
please help me on that. thanks in advance

Comment: I hope that you realize that if you want to set a variable, you need to use `$subscription = 1` not `$subscription == 1` which just compares the value of the variable to 1 but does nothing beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

Below, are some session variable-related notes, regarding x-cart 4.4.x branch.

With the `x_session_register()` function, each variable can be inserted in the `$XCART_SESSION_VARS` array and consequently, with the 
`x_session_save()` function, the session variables array is saved in the database.

Session data in xcart are saved in the `xcart_session_data` table, with primary key using the session id value of each visitor ('sessid' column) and all data being saved in serialized format in the 'data' column.

Example snippet:

```
if ($some_var == "Y"){
  x_session_register("my_var");  
  $my_var="true";
  x_session_save();
}

if($XCART_SESSION_VARS['my_var '] =="true")
  $smarty->assign("my_var", $my_var);
```

In case the `$XCART_SESSION_VARS` variable is not in scope, we declare it as global and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

In php file,

```
    if ($var1){
      x_session_register("my_var");  
      $my_var="content";
      x_session_save();
    }

    if($XCART_SESSION_VARS['my_var'] !=""){
      $smarty->assign("my_var", $XCART_SESSION_VARS['my_var']);
      x_session_unregister("my_var"); 
    }
```

in tpl file,

```
{if $my_var}
    {$my_var}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this in you php 
$smarty->assign('session',$_SESSION);

// OR in tpl
/*
{$session|print_r} // for above assignment

// OR
{php}
    print_r($_SESSION);
{/php}

// OR
{$smarty.session.*}

*/
```

Comment: php and tpl are in different location,
not asigned tpl in this php file.
not working.

Comment: Did you print your session in any php file may be it helps to debug it. Are you sure your session exists and what happen when you print {$smarty.session.*}

Comment: If your session exists so it must work according to http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if there are any variables in `$_SESSION`. Run in PHP (not in Smarty) `var_dump($_SESSION)` to make sure there are any variables in it

I looked at documentation and seems x-cart doesn't store session variables in the way you think (so there won't be variables in `$_SESSION`). It doesn't store sessions in `$_SESSION` but in some custom ways. You can look at http://kb.x-cart.com/display/XDD/Sessions+management

As no data is in `$_SESSION` when you try to use `$_SESSION` in Smarty it won't work. You need to use x-cart methods to get session variables and then assign them to Smarty